# Should I use Task.Run() for BackgroundService that does I/O

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asynchronous

I have an ASP.NET Core 5 API that needs to do some background tasks. These background tasks will run for the entirety of the applications life, and will be reading azure queues so spending a lot of time sitting doing nothing.

I have read that for I/O you shouldn't use Task.Run() as it's inefficient, but if in my case I'm not waiting on an I/O call, I'm waiting on a background task that happens to do a lot of I/O calls, is that ok? It seems if I don't use Task.Run() then every time my background task gets something from the queue and so the code after await continues, then it will be blocking some main thread in ASP that spooled up the task in the first place.

Comment: If it is queue based I wouldn't do it in a website. I'd have a separate service / process for doing the work. Note that isn't to do with efficiency - more to do with "what if this is shutdown mid process".

Comment: Alright, pretend I'm reading files then. Same question

Comment: If you are reading files, whether you use `Task.Run` or not is largely moot. The IO itself will be the bottleneck. Try it and see for yourself. Will it make a difference? Perhaps. But in practical terms unless you are under massive load I wouldn't worry. Do it however it seems simpler, and then profile if it is too slow for your purposes.

Comment: If my background service doesn't await on anything but has some kind of infinite loop, then it will not yield and give execution back to the code that called it, so the web server will be unresponsive. From my understanding, when the awaited piece completes, then the code that follows it is queued and executed later. I have assumed that this will be executed on the same thread that ran the initial calling code, which seems to be quite easy to block other ASP stuff. Will this code execute on the same thread that called it originally or a new one?

Comment: Have you had a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio ?

Comment: I've implemented BackgroundService base class, and am using the executeasync method.

Comment: So you are fine. Everything will work fine. You aren't going to block anything if you do it the way they suggest.

Comment: I appreciate the reassurance but I'm after more of an explanation as to what is going on here

Comment: Your mental model of how it works is wrong. You are worried it will block other things. It won't. I mean, I can go into the source code and try and prove it to you - but it is somewhat self evident. They aren't going to give you a means to do background stuff if (by design) it stops the website doing its main job. Basically `then it will be blocking some main thread in ASP that spooled up the task in the first place.` just isn't true. It doesn't work like that. I mean you can use `Task.Run` if you really want to. But it won't have the effect you think it will.

Comment: You're right, my misunderstanding was with the thread pool. After watching this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=il9gl8MH17s I see now that when you call await, the current async method saves its state, and the program continues doing whatever else it needed to. When the awaited method completes, the thread pool picks another thread (or the same one if that happened to be freed up in the meantime) and resets the state and allows the execution of the async function to continue. Because the thread pool manages that, it will not let you block the original thread after await has been called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> These background tasks will run for the entirety of the applications life, and will be reading azure queues so spending a lot of time sitting doing nothing.

I agree with others' comments: by far [the best solution is to move these out of the ASP.NET process completely](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/01/asynchronous-messaging-1-basic-distributed-architecture.html). Azure Functions, for example, has built-in support for Azure Storage Queues. Benefits of Azure Functions over ASP.NET in-process include:

- Your API (ASP.NET) can scale independently from your backend (Azure Function).
- Scaling on the backend is automatic. Up as high as you want, potentially down to zero.
- The backend process has its own thread pool, so there's no interference with the ASP.NET thread pool.

> I have read that for I/O you shouldn't use Task.Run() as it's inefficient

`Task.Run` should be avoided in ASP.NET's request processing pipeline. It's always inefficient regardless of the type of work being done.

`Task.Run` *can* be useful for background tasks in an ASP.NET process, in particular if there's blocking work done during startup of the background task.

The main thing with `Task.Run` on ASP.NET is that [you don't want to interfere with the ASP.NET thread pool heuristics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/async-programming-introduction-to-async-await-on-asp-net#asynchronous-code-is-not-a-silver-bullet). Regularly queueing work to the thread pool is a problem, since you're stealing threads and then re-injecting them on a regular basis. So using `Task.Run` when processing each HTTP request or when processing each queue item would be a bad idea. A single `Task.Run` done once at startup doesn't matter.

> It seems if I don't use Task.Run() then every time my background task gets something from the queue and so the code after await continues, then it will be blocking some main thread in ASP that spooled up the task in the first place.

This is a valid concern if there's blocking work being done during your message processing.

One way to think about `async`/`await` is that each method is broken up into pieces (at each `await` point), and each of those pieces is scheduled separately, one at a time. Each time a piece is scheduled, it takes a thread pool thread, runs the piece, and then returns the thread. As long as the work is fast, this is fine, but if one of those pieces has blocking work, then the ASP.NET thread pool heuristics can be impacted.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) to see how do do this in a separate process. That may be your best bet. You also use background processes within a web application if you want. Within the background task, use the synchronous API to do your I/O and use await.